# Classify Value Within Max/Min Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, unpivot

Using SQL Server 2012, I have a classification table that is something like this:

```
prodName   class1min   class1max   class2min   class2max   class3min   class3max
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
prod A      1.5         1.8         1.8         2.1         2.1         2.5
prod B      3.6         3.9         3.9         4.5         4.5         5.6
prod C      2.7         3.2         3.2         3.6         3.6         4.2
etc...
```

Given a product name and a value, I need to find what classification (1, 2 or 3) my value belongs in.

ie. I have a product B item with a value of 4.1. I just need to be able to identify that it belongs in class 2.

So far I have experimented with creating unpivot tables based on what product is selected, like this:

Prod B:

```
class       value
------------------
class1min   3.6
class1max   3.9
class2min   3.9
class2max   4.5
class3min   4.5
class3max   5.6
```

Then by inserting my value and sorting, I'm at least able to visualize the classification.

```
class       value
------------------
class1min   3.6
class1max   3.9
class2min   3.9
myvalue     4.1
class2max   4.5
class3min   4.5
class3max   5.6
```

I'm still having problems isolating it by code though, and I think there might be a better way.

*NOTE*: in the case of a tie, I'd like the lower classification.

Comment: 1. Normalize your data

Comment: @Strawberry Unfortunately it's not _my_ data, but if you have any suggestions as to how the table should be organized, I'd be happy to pass it on to the customer :)

Comment: Where does the value come from? A variable? What would a value of 1.8  (for Prod A) or 3.6 (for Prod C) be? It seems the classes overlap.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The value will be passed into a stored procedure that is responsible for returning the classification. In the actual table, the values are considerably more precise, so the chance of an exact match is unlikely though still possible. In that event, I am told to just take the lower classification match. Thanks.

Comment: SELECT..CASE WHEN value >=class1min and value <= class1max THEN 1 as class1,...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpivot the data and then perform the comparison.  Since you are using SQL Server 2012, then you can easily unpivot the `min`/`max` columns in sets using CROSS APPLY:

```
select prodname, class, [min], [max]
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  values
    ('class1', class1min, class1max),
    ('class2', class2min, class2max),
    ('class3', class3min, class3max)
) c(class, [min], [max])
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d636/3).  Once the data has been unpivoted, then you can compare your value to find the class. If you have more classifications, then you can easily add more values in the subquery:

```
DECLARE @Prod VARCHAR(32) = 'Prod B', 
  @val DECIMAL(10,2) = 4.1;

select prodname, class, [min], [max]
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  values
    ('class1', class1min, class1max),
    ('class2', class2min, class2max),
    ('class3', class3min, class3max)
) c(class, [min], [max])
where prodname = @Prod
  and @val > [min]
  and @val <= [max]
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d636/6)

Comment: +1 but in the case of a tie, they want the lower classification, so should be `> [min]` and `<= [max]`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Missed that in the comments, code has now been fixed. Thanks

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much. At what point in MS SQL was the cross apply functionality added?

Comment: @user3083337 SQL Server 2005 implemented the APPLY operator. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: What is the reason for putting the apply in a subquery?

Comment: @Anon it's not necessary, habit from working with pivots, removed the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only three possible classes, you can accomplish this quite simply with a `CASE` expression:

```
DECLARE @Prod VARCHAR(32) = 'Prod B', @val DECIMAL(10,2) = 4.1;

SELECT [Class] = CASE WHEN @val <= class1max THEN 'Class1'
    WHEN @val > class3Min THEN 'Class3' ELSE 'Class2' END
FROM dbo.tableName
WHERE ProdName = @Prod;
```

Now that we know that the "problem" is that you actually have 9 classifications, not the 3 as stated in the question, this still expands just fine:

```
DECLARE @Prod VARCHAR(32) = 'Prod B', @val DECIMAL(10,2) = 4.1;

SELECT [Class] = CASE WHEN @val <= class1max THEN 'Class1'
    WHEN @val > class2Min AND @val <= class2Max THEN 'Class2'
    WHEN @val > class3Min AND @val <= class3Max THEN 'Class3'
    WHEN @val > class4Min AND @val <= class4Max THEN 'Class4'
    WHEN @val > class5Min AND @val <= class5Max THEN 'Class5'
    WHEN @val > class6Min AND @val <= class6Max THEN 'Class6'
    WHEN @val > class7Min AND @val <= class7Max THEN 'Class7'
    WHEN @val > class8Min AND @val <= class8Max THEN 'Class8'
    ELSE 'Class9' END
FROM dbo.tableName
WHERE ProdName = @Prod;
```

If the problem with this is that it's too much code, well, you could consider changing the design.

Comment: This was my original approach, but there are actually 9 classifications versus the 3 that I put in this example. Thanks

Comment: This expands just fine to 9 classifications.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you ask, a normalized approach might look like this [with a PK formed on (prodname,class)]...

```
prodName   class  min    max  
prod A      1     1.5    1.8   
prod B      1     3.6    3.9   
prod C      1     2.7    3.2   
prod A      2     1.8    2.1   
prod B      2     3.9    4.5   
prod C      2     3.2    3.6   
prod A      3     2.1    2.5
prod B      3     4.5    5.6
prod C      3     3.6    4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented already you can simply normalize your data into multiple tables. e.g.

```
Product
--------
id_Product
name
moreProductRelatedColumns

ProductClassification
--------------
id_Classification
classCode
fk_productId
min
max
```

Then you can select by:

```
Select classCode 
from Products join ProductClassification pc on id_Product = fk_productId
where value between pc.min and pc.max
```

In your current Table design you can use nested CASE WHEN Statements. However I would suggest the normalized Table Design as you've no problems to add or remove classes from Products without rewriting your queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @target_product varchar(32) = 'prod B'
DECLARE @target_value decimal(9,2) = 4.1

SELECT LEFT([class],6)
FROM MyTable
UNPIVOT([value] FOR [class] IN (
  [class1min],[class1max],
  [class2min],[class2max],
  [class3min],[class3max]
)) p1
WHERE @target_product = [prodName]
GROUP BY prodName,LEFT([class],6)
HAVING @target_value >= MIN([value]) AND @target_value < MAX([value])
```